# Time elapsed for aborted computation?

Tags: timing

I have a computation which is taking very long

```
AbsoluteTiming[sr = ShellRegion@region];
```

Instead of getting $Aborted, is there a system method to get a time estimate of how long it was running before being aborted?

Comment: Do you mean you leave it running, press `Alt+.`, and then you want to see how long there in between the abort keystokes and when the evaluation queue is free again?

Comment: I think so yes, or until it freezes and I kill it

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `region`?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe the following construct suits your need, take for example

```
Module[{tic},
tic = SessionTime[];
CheckAbort[
Do[Print[n]; Pause[1], {n, 10}] (* here goes your expression *), 
SessionTime[] - tic
]
```

or wrapped in a convenient function

```
SetAttributes[try, HoldFirst]
try[expr_] := Module[{tic},
tic = SessionTime[];
CheckAbort[expr, SessionTime[] - tic]
]
```

that can be called with some expression you wish to evaluate

```
try[Do[Pause[1]; Print[n], {n, 10}]]
```

[image: animated gif]

Answer (score 6):

Simply wrapping your computation in `CheckAbort` as suggested by @Sascha seems to be sufficient to achieve most of what you want.  E.g.

```
AbsoluteTiming[CheckAbort[Pause[20], Null]]
```